# Load single CakePHP plugin with App::build()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Is it possible to load a single plugin from outside the cake root using App::build()?

If I do:

```
App::build(array(
    'Plugin' => array('/full/path/to/plugin_dir/')
));
```

..I can load a whole directory of plugins but what if I only want to use one of them?  Is this possible? (I get errors when using a path to the specific plugin directory).

(P.s. This is cake version 2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bootstrap.php in a baked application:

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit
```

You have to add the directory with the plugin in it via App::build() and then the plugin itself with the method above.

While using "App::build()" you are not "loading" all the files in there. You are defining the paths where cake searches for php to include in case it has to.
Nothing will be loaded if it is not need since Cakephp 2.0. Everythings is about lazy loading ^^

How this is, what you are searching for ;)